# Composite request causes Bad Request 400 now

Tags: rest-api, composite

We are accessing salesforce via rest api. We have multiple instances with different features/model and versions. Following works in the old instance but not in the new. It's using a composite post request to reference request 1 from request 2:

```
{
  "allOrNone": "false",
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v51.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+RecordType.Id,+RecordType.DeveloperName,+FirstName,+LastName,+Salutation,+Title,+CC_Language__c,+Email,+CC_Interests__c,+CC_Hash_ID__c,+CC_Country__c,+Phone,+MobilePhone,+OtherCountry,+OtherCity,+OtherPostalCode,+OtherState,+OtherStreet,+CC_Visitor_Group__c+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email='jon.doe@gmail.com'+AND+AccountId+=+'0010X00004apKnGQAU'+AND+RecordTypeId+=+'0120X0000009hgIQAQ'+LIMIT+1",
      "referenceId": "CurrentContact"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v51.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+CampaignId,+Status,+ContactId+FROM+CampaignMember+WHERE+Contact.Id+=+'@{CurrentContact.records[0].Id}'",
      "referenceId": "ContactCampaignMembers"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see there's a filter in the second that refers to the first:

```
Contact.Id+=+'@{CurrentContact.records[0].Id}'"
```

This works as expected and [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite.htm). But in my new instance composite requests work only if i filter with a static value not by referencing another request:

```
{
  "allOrNone": "false",
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email+=+'jon.doe@gmail.com'+AND+RecordTypeId+=+'0121x0000030snIAAQ'+LIMIT+1",
      "referenceId": "CurrentContact"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT+Lead__c,+Contact__c,+Subscription_Status__c,+Subscription_Date_dt__c,+Publication_Subscription__c.Id,+Publication_Subscription__c.ExtId__c,+Publication_Subscription__c.Name+FROM+Publication_Subscription__c+WHERE+Contact__c+=+'@{CurrentContact.records[0].Id}'",
      "referenceId": "Publications"
    }
  ]
}
```

The url (in postman) is: `{{API_URL}}/services/data/:version/composite`

This causes a 400 and just works if i replace `@{CurrentContact.records[0].Id}` with a static ContactId. What can be the reason? As far as i know there should be [no differences between version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_subrequest_result.htm) regarding this behavior.

Edit: It seems that the customer is using an API Gateway which might filter out queries that contain curly braces. At least this is my suspicion.

Comment: In your new instance, does the first GET request return any records? If yes, then recommend opening a case with SF support.

Comment: @identigral: yes, the first returns a record. But i guess i've found out the reason. It's not a salesforce issue, but the customer uses an Api Gateway which is an additional layer between us and salesforce. This seems to redirect to a 400 page if the query contains curly braces. So some kind of a security feature which doesn't work correctly. Maybe i should delete my question then.

Comment: How does API Gateway intercept this request?

Comment: @identigral: I'm not sure how it works, just i know that it exists. They still have the possibility for a direct access to salesforce on dev instance and there it works without a problem. So they need to fix it somehow, it's not my problem.